# How to set up a thread pool for an IOCP server with connections that may perform blocking operations

Tags: windows, threadpool, iocp

I'm currently working on a server application that's written in the proactor style, using select() + a dynamically sized thread pool (there's a simple mechanism based on keeping track of idle worker threads).

I need to modify it to use IOCP instead of select() on windows, and I'm wondering what the best way to utilize threads is.

For background information, the server has stateful, long-lived connections, and any request may require significant processing, and block. In fact, most requests call into customer-written code, which may block at will.

I've read that the OS can tell when an IOCP thread blocks, and unblock another one, but it doesn't look like there's any support for creating additional threads under heavy load, or if many of the threads are blocked.

I've read one site which suggested that you have a small, fixed-size thread pool which uses IOCP to deal with I/O only, which sends requests which can block to another, dynamically-sized thread pool. This seems non-optimal due to the additional thread synchronization required (although you can use IOCP as well for the tasks for the second thread pool), and the larger number of threads needed (extra context switching).

Is that the best way?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is.  You can easily keep track of how many threads are available, i.e., waiting for a completion packet, and start additional threads if the number drops too low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you've read is one of my articles on IOCP (most probably [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2337/A-reusable-high-performance-socket-server-class)). That's likely a bit out of date now as the whole problem that it sort to avoid (that of I/O being cancelled if the thread that issued it exits before the I/O completes) is no longer a problem with any of Microsoft's currently supported OS's (it's only an issue on XP and before).

You're correct in noticing that my design from 2000/2002 was sub optimal from a context switching point of view; but it worked pretty well at the time, given the constraints of the underlying API.

On a modern OS there's no real advantage in having separate thread pools for I/O and blocking work. A more modern solution would probably involve dynamically expanding and reducing the number of I/O threads servicing the IOCP as required.

You'd need to track the number of IOCP threads that are active (i.e. not waiting on GetQueuedCompletionStatus() ) and spawn more when there are "too few". Likewise just as a thread is about to go back and wait on GQCS you could check to see if you have "too many" and if so, let it die instead.

I should probably update those articles.